# What is this strange ore that I can't mine?

Tags: terraria

So I found this weird ore in the crimson tunnels, and I couldn't mine it at all, even with a cobalt pickaxe. No explosives worked, and the block wasn't listed on the wiki.

Anyone know what it is? And how to mine it?[image: Strange, white ore.]

Answer (score 9):

That looks like [Titanium Ore](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titanium_Ore). You can mine it with a [Mythril](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_Ore) or [Orichalcum](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Orichalcum_Ore) Pickaxe or Drill.

If you press <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the fullscreen map, you can hover your mouse over a block to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's Titanium, the alternate version of Admantite Ore. You can mine it with a Mythril or Orichalcum drill.

It should be on the wiki.